# How do I dynamically create a rails link_path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So I have 3 paths I want to generate links for:

```
confirmed_path  GET /confirmed(.:format)    posts#status {:status=>"confirmed"}
unconfirmed_path    GET /unconfirmed(.:format)  posts#status {:status=>"unconfirmed"}
corroborated_path   GET /corroborated(.:format) posts#status {:status=>"corroborated"}
```

In my view, I am rendering the relevant `span` that has this link like this:

```
<span class="post-status status label<%=render partial: "shared/color", locals: {post: post.status }%>"><%= link_to post.status.try(:upcase), "#" %></span>
```

What I want to happen is, without using unseemly if/case statements....the path portion of the `link_to`, if the `post.status` == "confirmed", I want it to produce `confirmed_path`.

I can't quite figure out how to get string interpolation to work for this type of problem...beause when I try:

```
link_to post.status.try(:upcase), "#{post.status}_path"
```

It literally produces the HTML "confirmed_path", versus `/confirmed`.

Any thoughts?

**Edit 1**

So I figured out one solution, but I am curious about other options:

```
link_to post.status.try(:upcase), "#{post.status.html_safe}"
```

That works perfectly.

Is there another way? A more "Railsy" way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this,

```
link_to post.status.try(:upcase), "#{post.status}_path"
```

the second argument to `link_to` is a string. What you actually want to do is call method (e.g. `confirmed_path`) whose name will be determined after string interpolation.

```
link_to post.status.try(:upcase), send("#{post.status}_path")
```

---

Also, since your routes map to the same action, you can define a single route instead of three.

```
get '/:status', to: 'posts#status', constraints: { status: /confirmed|unconfirmed|corroborated/ }, as: :status
```

Then, in your views, you can do something like,

```
<%= link_to post.status.try(:upcase), status_path(status: post.status) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try: `link_to post.status.try(:upcase), post.status`

Comment: That didn't work. That just outputs the same thing (i.e. "confirmed" versus the actual path of `/confirmed`).